# Schedule cancellable script to run after duration

Tags: bash, timeout, sleep

I want to be able to run a script after a certain duration has elapsed. I also want to be able to cancel it and reschedule it, i.e. increase the duration on-the-fly.

I was thinking of somthing like this ->

```
stop_prev_instance.sh; sleep 60 && /etc/init.d/myscript reload
```

My problem is I need the `stop_prev_instance.sh` to only stop the previous run if it was `sleep`ing, and not if the `/etc/init.d/myscript reload` command is running.

What would be the right way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `lockfile` (from procmail project) for such a "cancel-and-reload" script.

```
#!/bin/bash

SLEEP=$1
LOCKFILE="/tmp/reload.lock"
MYPID=$$
MYNAME=$(basename "$0")

lockfile "$LOCKFILE"
# kill all other scripts with the same name
KILLPIDS=$(pgrep "^${MYNAME:0:12}" | grep -v "^$MYPID\$")
kill $KILLPIDS 2>/dev/null
rm -f "$LOCKFILE"

sleep "$SLEEP"

lockfile "$LOCKFILE"
/etc/init.d/myscript reload
rm -f "$LOCKFILE"
```

At most *one* script will be executing between the `lockfile` and the `rm` commands.

Note, the `reload-lock` file should be better placed somewhere where only one user has write permissions (not `/tmp`!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not a bash guy so I maybe wrong, but this solution doesn't seem to satisfy my requirement to stop all previous instances of the script.

Comment: All I had in my `stop_prev_instance.sh` was something like a `kill -INT `pgrep myscript``, and it wasn't working as mentioned in the question. :( 
Could you please update your answer with a working implementation of such a script (or perhaps add it directly to above script)?

Comment: @user3490458 I've added some code to kill the other previous scripts, hopefully it's good enough.